# XSLT storing or saving values and use them in another for loop

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the situation where i need to store some values inside the first for loop and use that stored values in second for loop.
For storing values i have used  but this variable is local to for loop. I have also tried declaring variable as global and tried concatenating values to it apparently i dont get concatenated value in second for loop. 
Here i need to understand if there is any way i can save the values in a variable and use it for later purpose. Like similar to array or some sort thing.

If you give me some example on this that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Variables are "immutable" in XSLT, and so can't be changed when first set. You will probably need to approach your problem in a different way. It would help if you posted your XML, and explained what you were trying to achieve, and then hopefully a different solution can be found. Thanks!

Comment: This is well-known technique in XSLT 1.0. Put the sorting inside the body of an `<xsl:variable>`. Then define another `xsl:variable` whose content is the result of the `xxx:node-set()` function applied on the first variable. Now, you can use the second variable as a separate tree.

Comment: @dimitre Thanks for your explanation. It would help me if you give simple example please.

Comment: MadhuCM, I am at work -- will be glad to provide the requested example -- 7-8 hours from now.

Comment: Thank you. I tried doing concat the values inside the for loop and assign it to the global variable but when I access this global variable outside the for loop I always get empty.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I did it in alternative way. 
I have created two static methods in Java class one for Storing the value and other for retrieving the value. And these static methods are called inside the xslt wherever you wish to store/retrieve the values. Using this approach now i can easily add as many values i want and extract them whenever i needed them.

Comment: @MadhuCM, If this is so, you shouldn't use XSLT at all. Forget about it... On the other side, if you really want to learn, read more.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev you are right this is not actual way to do. But i didnt find any example for my requirement here so i had to end up doing this approach.

Comment: @MadhuCM, Had you provided an actual example, a complete and small XML document, and the exact wanted result from the transformation, then many people would be able to give a pure XSLT solution. You can still do this.

Answer (score 0):

@DimitreNovatchev I did it in alternative way. 
I have created two static methods in Java class one for Storing the value and other for retrieving the value. And these static methods are called inside the xslt wherever you wish to store/retrieve the values. Using this approach now i can easily add as many values i want and extract them whenever i needed them.